# get URL of the image if it's not an image?

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, reddit

I have the following function which uses Reddit's JSON api to list the latest Rage Comic from the subreddit "/r/fffffffuuuuuuuuuuuu." I have it pull the image URL and output it as an img. The problem however, is that sometimes the submitted comic uses the link to the image on 'imgur.com' rather than the direct link, which is on 'i.imgur.com.'

I initially tried splitting the requested URL so I only get the string after the '/' but the issue was still that it didn't contain the image type (ie. '.png', '.jpg', etc).

My question is, how can I get the img src for URL's that aren't the direct img src from i.imgur.com?

As you can see from the below code, the only solution I have at the moment is to output an error if the img isn't there.

Here's the function:

```
var i = -1;

function rage(data) {
    var rageURL = data['data']['children'][i]['data']['url'];
    $('#comic .rage-wrap').html('<img src="'+rageURL+'" />');
    $('img').load(function() { $('.rage-wrap').fadeIn(400); });
    $('img').error(function() { alert('whoops!'); });

};
function nextRage() {
    $('.next-rage').live('click', function() {
        $('.rage-wrap').fadeOut(400);
        i++;
        $.ajax({
          type: "GET",
          url: "http://www.reddit.com/r/fffffffuuuuuuuuuuuu/.json",
          dataType: "jsonp",
          jsonp: "jsonp",
          success: rage
      });     
    });

};
```

Answer (score 0):

For the time being you can skip such urls that don't end in .png, .jpg, .jpeg, .gif or other image extensions. The next step would be to actually load the target url on imgur (note: not all links will be pointing to imgur.com but majority are) and retrieve the image from the html which would be a bit tough using jquery. Also, imgur or other sites have a feature where they allow slideshows. What will you do in those cases?